# Map a network drive for a different user using psexec -s with their password

Tags: registry, windows-8.1, psexec, network-share, net-use

I know how to map a network drive using `net use` and `psexec`. Out of convenience for my users, I don't want to make them do anything, really. Just request the share and that's it. I want to do the rest without inconveniencing their work at all - in the background. I don't want to change their password to use `net use x: \\server\where\share\is\ -u username -p password`. I don't really want to make them download a BAT file. I could transfer a BAT file to their Desktop using psexec -s. However, That still requires them to click on a file and interact with technology I love, but they hate LOL.

How do I map a network drive to another user on the computer if I am logged in as an admin with `SYSTEM` permissions because of `psexec -s`?

I know the Registry is a database of configurations, I researched and read so many articles about it and blogs, but cannot find anything that discusses copying or moving registry configurations from one folder to another one. I researched the web about this, and need to find out if it can be done manually, which I can then script. But, I don't know how. Do I just do that with Windows Explorer or use `move` to move its supporting files.

Here is what I have in mind:

1. net use x: \share\name /persistent:yes (makes the drive available to my profile)
2. Read `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList`

However using `reg query /v "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList"` I get `ERROR: Invalid key name.` and if done without `/ve` or `/v`, I get `ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.`; however, using `regedit.exe`, I can browse to it.

2. Parse the target username and find its user ID under `HKEY_USERS`
3. Move the drive letter information from my profile because using psexec -s used my admin profile on the computer, `HKEY_USERS\{S-S-WHATEVER}\Blah\Network\X` to the target user's registry folder in `HKEY_USERS\S-S-WHATEVER2\blah\Network\`

Technet does not explain this and neither does any article I found in the last 3 hours.

Thank you for your help! If you help me get the commands right, that would be amazing, and I will give you a $ tip if that is legal on SOF.

Comment: Even if you were to successfully add the relevant registry entries, the user would need to log off and back on for them to have any effect.  Nor can `psexec` help you in this case as far as I can see.  Perhaps you could write a program or script that starts automatically when the user logs on and runs in the background, and have that program automatically run batch files you drop in a particular folder?

Comment: That's a great idea and maybe a little easier. However, dropping files in folders requires an entire approval process here. With the `/persistent:yes` option, won't that work persist a logoff / reboot? Because I can live with that. Also, I am technically curious as to how to accomplish this with making changes to the registry. Please enlighten me. I am willing to tip for the lesson.

Comment: Network drives mappings are local to the user's logon session.  Running a program in another user's logon session is complicated, search on WTSQueryUserToken for examples.  (The psexec tool can run code in a specified Remote Desktop session, but that's not the same thing.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston Thank you for that information. It perhaps makes more sense to have the user run a Batch file I place on their Desktops. Still is less steps than opening File Explorer -> This PC -> Map Network Drive, copying/pasting location, etc.